# Spring MVC / Jackson: Reset objectMapper after completition

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Lets say I have two resources and both return JSON. For request1 I want to use a jackson mixin to prepare the returned JSOn. For request2 I do not want to use any mixins.

Question: How to reset mixins after request1? The object mapper is a spring bean / singleton.

Code:

```
@ResponseBody
public Something getSomething1(..) {
  ..
  objectMapper.addMixIn(Something.class, MyMixin.class);
  return obj;
}

@ResponseBody
public Something getSomething2(..) {
  ..
  return obj;
}
```

Of course I can unset the mixins in getSomething2() and in ALL other methods at the beginning but I rather want to do it after the completition of getSomething1. So the method which modified the objectMapper should undo its changes.

EDIT:
As JBNizet mentioned, this is not thread-safe. Does anyone know a better way how to use jackson mixins only in one method?

Comment: I don't have any good solution to provide, but your desired solution wouldn't be right: the ObjectMapper is a singleton, used by all controllers, and requests are handled concurrently, by multiple controllers, or multiple methods of the same controller.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree. But do you know a better way how to use those mixins only in one method?

Comment: Except for creating and configuring your own ObjectMapper instance, and serializing the response body explicitly using this mapper, no. An alternative could be to use a JSON view, as described here: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring. Or simply to transform your Something to an object that has the right structure.

Comment: @JBNizet JSON View is perfect. Please file an answer that I can accept :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ObjectMapper.copy()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#copy()) to create a new `ObjectMapper` with the same configuration as the original.  Then add your custom MixIns into the new `ObjectMapper` instance.